# Stripe Reporting API csv file returns valid headers but has no rows?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using the Stripe API via Postman to retrieve Reporting API data, in this instance I am trying to retrieve - as you can see from the file I have downloaded below the headers appear correct and I have made various successful transactions that have completed in my test Stripe account.

When I attempt to download the payout files direct from the dashboard these all have valid headers and data rows in them, however when I do this via the API it appears to return empty rows as illustrated below.

[image: CSV output]

I have created the reporting runs and set the time dates and then using the `{{baseUrl}}/v1/reporting/report_runs/frr_1OYsDeHpBAlTJ9LaKaZJPWCn` request have go the following output :

```json
{
    "id": "frr_1OYsDeHpBAlTJ9LaKaZJPWCn",
    "object": "reporting.report_run",
    "created": 1705333018,
    "error": null,
    "livemode": false,
    "parameters": {
        "interval_end": 1705276800,
        "interval_start": 1702944000
    },
    "report_type": "payout_reconciliation.itemized.5",
    "result": {
        "id": "file_1OYsE0HpBAlTJ9LaHP83ElFn",
        "object": "file",
        "created": 1705333040,
        "expires_at": 1736869040,
        "filename": "frr_1OYsDeHpBAlTJ9LaKaZJPWCn.csv",
        "links": {
            "object": "list",
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": "link_1OYtbbHpBAlTJ9LaAhALJNLt",
                    "object": "file_link",
                    "created": 1705338347,
                    "expired": false,
                    "expires_at": null,
                    "file": "file_1OYsE0HpBAlTJ9LaHP83ElFn",
                    "livemode": false,
                    "metadata": {},
                    "url": "https://files.stripe.com/links/MDB8YWNjdF8xT1A0clRIcEJBbFRKOUxhfGZsX3Rlc3RfZWJkVnowU1JkNEh3VW1JTHEwdDJoeWhi00LKHMAhaA"
                },
                {
                    "id": "link_1OYta2HpBAlTJ9LaVmCJZDUV",
                    "object": "file_link",
                    "created": 1705338250,
                    "expired": false,
                    "expires_at": null,
                    "file": "file_1OYsE0HpBAlTJ9LaHP83ElFn",
                    "livemode": false,
                    "metadata": {},
                    "url": "https://files.stripe.com/links/MDB8YWNjdF8xT1A0clRIcEJBbFRKOUxhfGZsX3Rlc3RfcXlhTm9LdXR0ekRoWWx6UWJ0eTBUcngz00Bjfm8xi2"
                }
            ],
            "has_more": false,
            "url": "/v1/file_links?file=file_1OYsE0HpBAlTJ9LaHP83ElFn"
        },
        "purpose": "finance_report_run",
        "size": 170,
        "title": "FinanceReportRun frr_1OYsDeHpBAlTJ9LaKaZJPWCn",
        "type": "csv",
        "url": "https://files.stripe.com/v1/files/file_1OYsE0HpBAlTJ9LaHP83ElFn/contents"
    },
    "status": "succeeded",
    "succeeded_at": 1705333040
}
```

When I download the file in the URL - it has empty rows just the CSV header rows? What am I doing wrong? Any ideas..
https://files.stripe.com/v1/files/file_1OYsE0HpBAlTJ9LaHP83ElFn/content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the UI when seeing this report, are you using the same time interval like when you generated this report by API? Also make sure that you’re seeing the same report type. The one you’re using is payout_reconciliation.itemized.5, which corresponds to Itemized payout reconciliation.

I think the most likely explanation is that there are no data for this report type in this time period. You might be using different parameters on the UI.